# Log denied host IPs

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

I want to log IP Address of clients which tried to access my site , but unable  due to blocking  in .htaccess using DENY FROM syntax .
Please guide me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they'll come up in error.log as entries where the HTTP Status code is 403 Forbidden.

Comment: Can i maintain it in separate log file

Comment: Probably not, but it shouldn't be too difficult to parse out with a Perl script.